Why Arcpy can work and cannot work at the same time in the same Python environment?
I am working with arcpy in Visual Studio Code. In the same environment, arcpy can work for some codes and cannot work for others. For example, in this code "Reading_Netcdf_File.py":
import arcpy
import xarray as xr

data_Bio_acetaldehyde = path_Netcdf_Bio + "CAMS-GLOB-BIO_Glb_0.25x0.25_bio_acetaldehyde_v3.1_monthly_2022.nc"
data_Bio_acetone = path_Netcdf_Bio + "CAMS-GLOB-BIO_Glb_0.25x0.25_bio_acetone_v3.1_monthly_2022.nc"
data_Bio_butanes_and_higher_alkanes = path_Netcdf_Bio + "CAMS-GLOB-BIO_Glb_0.25x0.25_bio_butanes-and-higher-alkanes_v3.1_monthly_2022.nc"
data_Bio_butenes_and_higher_alkenes = path_Netcdf_Bio + "CAMS-GLOB-BIO_Glb_0.25x0.25_bio_butenes-and-higher-alkenes_v3.1_monthly_2022.nc"
### Reading ... (CAMS GLOB BIO DATAS)
print ("Successfully Reading Netcdf File!!!")

output_folder_Bio = "F:/Emission/CAMS_GLOB_BIO_TIFF/"
for substance in substance_Bio:
    for time in time_Data_2022:
        ds_Bio = xr.open_dataset(globals().get(f"data_Bio_{substance}", 0))
        for variable in variable_Bio:
            if variable in ds_Bio.variables:
                print(f"data_Bio_{substance}", time)
                out_raster_layer = f"{variable}_{substance}_Bio_{time[:10].replace('/', '').replace(':', '').replace(' ', '')}"
                out_raster_path = output_folder_Bio + out_raster_layer + ".tif"
                arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(globals().get(f"data_Bio_{substance}", 0), variable,
                                                "lon", "lat", out_raster_layer, dimension_values=[("time", time)])
                arcpy.CopyRaster_management(out_raster_layer, out_raster_path)

print("Successfully Executing Code!!!")

When I execute it in visual studio code and in command prompt it works smoothly
But at the same environment, there's also a file "Changing_Coordinate_System.py":
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os, datetime
from osgeo import ogr
import rasterio
import xarray as xr
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
import subprocess, time
from tqdm import tqdm

path_tiff_files = "F:/Emission/CAMS_GLOB_AIR_TIFF/"
raw_name = os.listdir(path_tiff_files)
outnames = []
for rname in raw_name:
    portion = os.path.splitext(rname)
    temp_name = portion[0] + '.tif'
    outnames.append(temp_name)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = path_tiff_files
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "ALL")
for raster in rasters:
    print(raster)

When I execute this code in both visual studio code and command prompt, it fails and the errors appear:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Emission_Python\Changing_Coordinate_System.py", line 3, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._base import *
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgisscripting\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from ._arcgisscripting import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arcgisscripting: The specified procedure could not be found.

Here's the image:
Image of Errors
I have try a lot of things such as:
Checking the Environment Path -> Nothing is strange
Python Path
Checking the Init file of Arcgisscripting -> Nothing is strange
I search many websites but no web can fit my problems
So I desperate and give up searching the reason for why arcpy can and cannot works at the same time in the same environment.
(Note: I use Arcgis Pro V.3.0.1 - Python V.3.9.11)

Wait I don't know how this work but by putting
import arcpy to the top, it does actually work.
Maybe the libraries conflict?
